# How to avoid re-use socket?

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

There is a server, there are clients. Clients connect to the server. Servers function "accept"  returns socket connected client. But when the client socket becomes invalid, it can be reused. How to prevent the server to reuse the same socket?
P.S.: For fans downvote pay attention, I'm not asking about a socket server, I ask about a client sockets.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you specify the actual problem you are trying to solve there might be other ways to solve it.

Comment: *"I'm not asking about a socket server, I ask about a client sockets."* is very vague - I assume you mean that you're not asking about the *listening* socket.  *"How to prevent the server to reuse the same socket?"* - you can't (on any implementation I've ever seen), and shouldn't try to.  For IP4 at least (I don't know about IP6), port numbers are 16 bit values and you'd run out pretty quick if e.g. a web server insisted on different port numbers every time.

Comment: @MaxZS: each connected socket is characterised by the two IP:port endpoints, and managed by the owning process using a file descriptor.  I have no idea how to reconcile that with your last comment.  Once one client disconnects from the server's port X, a later accept() may re-use the same server-side port number X: you can't avoid that.  Is that your question or not?  If not, can you restate your question more clearly?

Comment: I agree with TonyD. Your terminology is a bit mixed up as already pointed out and it is entirely unclear what you are asking. How does a "client socket becomes invalid" (do you mean closed)? And what do you understand by "reuse socket". In Linux, the socket is represented by a file descriptor. Are you saying you don't want the same file descriptor value to be reused for the next accepted socket?

Comment: @MaxZS - You have no control over the remote host.  It can shut down or someone can unplug it.  And there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @MaxZS You need to clearly state the problem you have.  Why is reusing a socket on your server bad?

Comment: Not necessarily stupid or uninteresting. It's just that the way you have worded the question makes it almost impossible to understand what you are asking. The official SO reason: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @MaxZS because server ports must be known by clients in order to know where to connect. But the ports opened on the server machine associated to clients are irrelevant (doesn't matter what value they have).

Comment: @MaxSZ, I have a feeling that the question really is "how to prevent the same client from connecting to the same TCP server more than once".

Answer (score 2):

This is just to clear up some misconceptions - I'm still voting for the question to be closed unless it's edited into something sensible.

> But when the client socket becomes invalid, it can be reused

No, the socket file descriptor has to be closed if the TCP connection has shut down. A new socket could be allocated later for a new TCP connection, and receive a file descriptor with the same integer value, but it isn't the same socket.

> The socket - this is not just a port, but also the address.

No, a socket is the handle your process uses to talk to the OS about a TCP connection, which is itself uniquely identified by the 4-tuple consisting of two ports and two addresses. See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/171783/39877), I'm not going to paste it all here.

> If no connection, then the customer will not be aware of this [closing a socket]

If there is no connection, there's nothing to close.

If there is an existing TCP connection, and either the client or server close their socket, the other end will be notified, and the other end's socket will also become invalid (and should be closed in response).

> For example, socket have parameters SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT. Why would they?

When you close a connection, you send a packet telling the other end of the connection that you've done so. Even after they've acknowledged this, you could receive other packets on the same connection, if they took a different network path. So, TCP keeps the closed connection around in TIME_WAIT state, preventing another connection starting on the same address:port tuple, for some arbitrary time until it's very unlikely to receive a packet that was really intended for the previous connection.

This arbitrary TIME_WAIT duration is 4 minutes, which is easily long enough that you could, for example, kill a server process and then restart it (at which point it will fail to bind to its address:port, because the closed connection is still using that address:port).

SO_REUSEADDR allows the server to replace the old TIME_WAIT connection with its new, live connection.

SO_REUSEPORT allows multiple sockets to bind to, and accept on, the same port for load-balancing purposes.

This is all documented, eg. in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), and neither option has anything to do with the socket file descriptor value.

As bolov said in a comment, the reason these are used by the server is that you actually care about the address:port bound by a server, because that's how you know where to reach it. The local port of a client connection is generally assigned from the ephemeral port range, and no-one cares what its value is except that it's unique at that moment in time.

Comment: Thanks for such elaborative explanation from each misconception in current discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible by creating such program that on not accepting by the server the `socket id` [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) is released. But this can complicate the OS may be a scenario that OS may failed.

`file descriptors` for a `single process`, `file table` and `inode table` available. As each `file descriptor` may be directed by individual `inode`.

[But](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) maximum number of `inodes` is fixed at file system creation, limiting the maximum number of files the file system can hold. A typical allocation heuristic for `inodes` in a file system is one percent of total size.

As `indoe table` has fixed size and on releasing the `file descriptor` that particular `inode` is free, but as per your way `inode table` may be dry up soon and crash the system.

Comment: Are you suggesting that leaking through your 64k IPv4 ports is likely to exhaust your inodes (assuming they're really associated with an inode)?

Comment: I am also not saying about the IPv4 or IPv6 port will exhaust, but as per the socket [mapage][1] return value, file descriptor returned.   [1]: http://linux.die.net/man/2/socket

Comment: A file descriptor is not an inode.

Comment: Yes you are right. But every file descriptor having file table and inode table, there can be scenario also that a inode representing multiple file descriptor, but on the reverse side every file descriptor belongs to inode definitely.